# When and why does embedded Electronic Control Unit (ECU) use default calibration values?

Tags: microcontroller, calibration

Typical embedded ECU stores real calibration values and default calibration values in Non-Volatile Memory (NVM).

Let's say ECU is Steering Controller and its primary function is Lane Keep Assist (LKA). It is mounted in a commercial truck.  It programs camera's real and default calibration values in NVM.

Mostly, real calibration values are used.  When and why are default calibration values used?

Comment: What do these calibration values do?

Comment: I just joined this project.  I'm not the developer on this project.  These values calibrate the  camera mounted on the commercial truck.  Camera takes images of road and provides them to Image Processing Unit(IMU) and Steering Control Module.  Steering control module sends commands to Torque Overlay System to keep vehicle in the lane.

Comment: And how are those "real" calibration values determined?  Is it a one-time measurement when the camera is mounted on the truck?  Does it happen dynamically each time the system is turned on?

Answer (score 2):

For factory testing or field service.

You flash the software in production and the device needs to be able to boot. Therefore, default calibration values that make 'some sense' are required. As soon as the device is 'known-good', you go on and do some kind of calibration overwriting the factory defaults.

Now the device is shipped to the assembly plant.

But the default values can still be kept in flash in case some sort of 'reset' is implemented. For example a service worker could reset the device (or parts of it) and initialize it with some sort of self calibration in the field if it does not work correctly any longer.